# Non-persistent attributes in Mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose as a mapper to MongoDB for my NodeJS project. I want to be able to have non-persistent attributes that do not get written to the database. For instance, I want to store things such as hashed password, username, and email. On the other hand, things that change frequently such as socket id and location, I want to be able to include such things in my schema without having the overhead to writing them to the database all the time. I've read about virtual attributes in Mongoose doc., however, the examples just merely combine existing persistent attributes as oppose to using a new non-persistent attribute.

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    gender: String,
    location: {
        lat: String,
        lng: String
    },
    password: String
});

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password)
{
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password)
{
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

In my code above, I want to somehow store `lat/lng` as a non-persistent attribute.

Comment: Why do you want them in your schema if you don't want them in the database? What's the use-case?

Comment: @robertklep is it  a better way to wrap the schema and temporary variables into a class? For instance, if I had a user class that has a schema object that contains persistent attributes along with temporary object that contains non-persistent attributes.

Comment: That sounds complicated. I'm still interested in the actual use-case that you have for wanting these non-persistent properties, because there might be an easy solution for a perceived problem.